# Using regexp in a windows bat file with BRC32 renaming utility

Tags: regex, batch-file

I am using Windows XP and wrote a simple bat file that goes out and downloads XML from a website then it renames the xml files so they all have a .zip extension but for some reason it won't rename the files.  Here is the line of code that doesn't work using BRC32, it seems to have trouble doing a REGEXP in windows.

```
.\software\BRC32 /DIR: /REGEXP:.*%22(.*)%22:\1.zip /EXECUTE

File Name:  download@down_stds=all&down_typ=results&cond=%22Aicardi Syndrome%22

Desired result: download@down_stds=all&down_typ=results&cond=%22Aicardi Syndrome%.zip
```

I am using the BRC32.exe utility that also uses the pcre.dll version 3.9 to do the REGEXP in the bat file, but for some reason I just get an error that says the file could not be renamed.  Does anyone have any insight into this problem>?

Comment: Is that really the filename?  '&' isn't a legal filename character.  In any case, if the command works from the command line, but not from the batch file, the variable substitution in the batch file is a likely culprit--change %var to %%var.  There's a reason for this that I can't recall

Comment: That simple change from % to %% fixed it wow thanks I was banging my head on this for a while.  Because it did work form the commnad line but not my scipt.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ben - er, `&` most certainly is a valid filename character. So is `%` for that matter. And `^`. And `(;)` too. All very difficult to deal with in batch. Best avoided - but some people insist on using them...

Comment: You're right, my bad.  And you're right twice--just because you *can* do a thing, doesn't mean you should :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing '%' to '%%' in the script fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say what BRC32' syntax is, I'd make a guess at the `/REGEXP:.*%22(.*)%22:\1.zip` part.

If the parser doesn't object to `%22(,*)%` it's likely to be resolved to [nothing].

If you really want to poke `%` as a parameter-character, then try doubling the `%`s since `%` escapes `%`.

But also, 22 look ssuspiciously like a `"` to me. Possibly you could replace the `%22` with `"` - but without knowing exactly what the parameter means, it's hard to advise.

But `."(.*)"\1.zip` looks very strange too...

Answer (score 0):

yep. adding another % sign fixed it. damn I feel so stupid